# Windows 10 - WiFi periodically disconnects from university network

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

My laptop is an Asus X550L running on Windows 10. The WiFi driver is Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter.

The WiFi is periodically disconnecting from the eduroam network of my university. This does not seem to happen when I am home. Once it is disconnected, I cannot re-connect and I need to restart the laptop completely so it is back on. When it is in this "post-disconnection state", I cannot connect to any other WiFi either (I've tried tethering from my Android phone multiple times, it displays the network name, but fails to connect).

I had similar issues with my laptop before (including with my home WiFi), but it seemed solved when I updated the driver with Snappy Driver Installer ("Update Driver Software..." from Device Manager was returning "The best driver software for your device is already installed").

Any insights?

I am currently looking at whether the disconnection always happens after a specific amount of time, but it does not feel like that...

Comment: It's a feature : you've spent enough time trawling the net and now it's telling you to do some work ::: :) :)

Comment: Driver installer, Go to the product website for your adapter and download the driver directly from the OEM.  ASUS has the drivers you should be using

Answer (score 0):

It could be a firmware problem, I would go to https://www.asus.com/support/Download-Center/ and see what your laptop is out of date on.

Recommendation: fully update hardware and drivers, then make sure windows 10 is fully updated. If you still have the issue then it could be faulty hardware or a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable adapter and re-enable via “Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections” to confirm that if you can re-connect the wife without system rebooting.

You may try to re-install another NIC driver version and check the result.

Answer (score 0):

Install the unsigned Atheros driver version 10.0.0.355 from Snappy Driver installer. It seems to be the most stable driver that works.